# React and Typescript creating useReducer "no overload matches this call"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import { useCallback, useReducer } from "react";

const ARTIST_REDUCER_TYPES = {
  ADD: "ADD",
};

const artistArray = [...Object.values(ARTIST_REDUCER_TYPES)] as const;

type ActionReturnedTypes = (typeof artistArray)[number];

type ReducerStateType = {
  artist: { name: string };
  albums: { name: string, released: number }[];
  topTracks: { name: string released: number }[];
};

type ReducerAction = {
  type: ActionReturnedTypes;
  payload: ReducerStateType;
};

const artistInitState = {
  artist: { name: ""},
  albums: [{name: "", released: 0}],
  topTracks: [{name: "", released: 0}],
};

export const useArtistResults = (initialState: typeof artistInitState) => {
  const [artistDetails, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (state: ReducerStateType, action: ReducerAction): ReducerStateType => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case ARTIST_REDUCER_TYPES.ADD: {
          if (!action.payload) {
            throw new Error("ADD action requires a payload");
          }

          return {
            ...state,
            artist: action.payload.artist,
            albums: action.payload.albums,
            topTracks: action.payload.topTracks,
          };
        }
      }
    },
    artistInitState
  );

  const setProfile = useCallback(
    (artist, albums, topTracks) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "ADD",
        payload: {
          artist,
          albums,
          topTracks,
        },
      });
    },
    []
  );
```

This is constantly returning this error:

> No overload matches this call.

If I take off the type for the state parameter the error goes away. I just don't seem to know what is causing this. Does this have something to do with the state object not matching the initial state?

I'm so confused

Comment: Can you edit the question to add a screenshot of where (which line) the error is coming from please?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar I fixed it but thanks anyways. I answered it

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the explicit `ReducerStateType` return type from the reducer function and adding a const assertion to `ARTIST_REDUCER_TYPES`:

```js
const ARTIST_REDUCER_TYPES = {
  ADD: "ADD",
} as const;
```

This changes the type of that value from:

```js
{
   ADD: string
}
```

to:

```js
{
  readonly ADD: "ADD"
}
```

This allows TypeScript to know that the `switch` inside your reducer is exhaustive.

Comment: Thanks man, but I fixed it and answered it.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the actual type for the state being slightly incorrect with the initial state.

My above code was an attempt at making it as reproducible as possible. In reality, my code and state is a lot larger than the example I put above so it wasn't a good example

All I had to do was fix the initialState

```
export const artistInitState = {
  artist: {
    external_urls: { spotify: "" },
    followers: { href: null, total: 0 },
    genres: [],
    href: "",
    id: "",
    images: [{ height: 0, url: "", width: 0 }],
    name: "",
    popularity: 0,
    type: "",
    uri: "",
  },
  albums: [
    {
      album_group: "",
      album_type: "",
      artists: [],
      available_markets: [],
      external_urls: { spotify: "" },
      href: "",
      id: "",
      images: [{ height: 0, url: "", width: 0 }],
      name: "",
      release_date: "",
      release_date_precision: "",
      total_tracks: 0,
      type: "",
      uri: "",
    },
  ],
  topTracks: [
    {
      album: {
        album_group: "",
        album_type: "",
        href: "",
      },
      artists: [],
      disc_number: 0,
      duration_ms: 0,
      explicit: false,
      external_ids: { isrc: "" },
      external_urls: {
        spotify: "",
      },
      href: "",
      id: "",
      is_local: false,
      is_playable: true,
      name: "",
      popularity: 0,
      preview_url: "",
      track_number: 0,
      type: "",
      uri: "",
    },
  ],
};
```

There were a few mistakes in there so it didn't match the ReducerStateType

```
type ReducerStateType<T> = {
  artist: ArtistDetailsType;
  albums: AlbumDetailsType[] | T;
  topTracks: TopTracksDetailsType[] | T;
};
```

```
export const useArtistResults = (initialState: typeof artistInitState) => {
  const [artistDetails, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (
      state: ReducerStateType<NoAlbumOrTracksType>,
      action: ReducerAction
    ): ReducerStateType<NoAlbumOrTracksType> => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case ARTIST_REDUCER_TYPES.ADD: {
          if (!action.payload) {
            throw new Error("ADD action requires a payload");
          }

          let albums: AlbumDetailsType[] | { noAlbums: "no albums" } = action
            .payload.albums.length
            ? [
                ...new Map(
                  action.payload.albums.map((item) => [item.name, item])
                ).values(),
              ]
            : { noAlbums: "no albums" };

          let topTracks: TopTracksDetailsType[] | { noTracks: "no tracks" } =
            action.payload.topTracks.length
              ? action.payload.topTracks
              : { noTracks: "no tracks" };

          return {
            ...state,
            artist: action.payload.artist,
            albums,
            topTracks,
          };
        }
        default:
          return { ...state };
      }
    },
    initialState
  );

  const setProfile = useCallback<ArtistAndAlbumStateSetter>(
    (artist, albums, topTracks) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "ADD",
        payload: {
          artist,
          albums,
          topTracks,
        },
      });
    },
    []
  );

  const { artist, albums, topTracks } = artistDetails;

  return { artist, albums, topTracks, setProfile };
};
```